# Create log file when installing rpm

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

What the best way to create a log file in an rpm spec file? The service I'm creating runs under an unprivileged user so cannot create files in /var/log/.

Comment: I think a minimal approach is accessible by a simple echo command during executing every scriptlet of specfile.

Answer (score 3):

You could create `/var/log/myservice/` directory and make it owned by your user.
Inside %install or make install: (ignoring buildroot & such)

```
install -d /var/log/myservice -o serviceuser -m 750
```

This assumes you are running your service similarly to apache which often runs as user `apache` and still puts logs in `var/log/apache`

Then add the corresponding rule for `/var/log/myservice` in your spec file.

```
%dir /var/log/myservice
```

Comment: Good idea, but rpmbuilid complains that the user doesn't exist

Comment: How about adding the directory normally, and useradd'ing and chown'ing it in %post ?

Comment: +1 but you actually want to useradd in %pre and specify the owner user/group in the %files section